# Import MongoDB (collection) into Python code

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have next question. I created some collection in MongoDB, which I can manipulate with my Command Prompt. The DB is called `db` and collection name is `test`.
Now, I want to manipulate the data with the Python code. So I have installed `pymongo` and created next code:

```
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient()
print client
db = client['db']
collection = db['test']
```

I expected on this place to see my collection `test` in the table form. After I brief the next prompt:

```
print collection.find_one()
```

I got the output `None`.
I suppose, the connection to my MongoDB doesn't work, how I can improve it and get my table in Python, like for example CSV file?

Actually, I DON'T want create new table in python and import it to MongoDB, just open already existing file from MongoDB in python code.

Comment: Your error looks like either the database or the collection don't exist (mongo doesn't raise any error if you try to access a nonexisting collection). Is the `mongod` daemon running? If you don't pass the URL/port pymongo expect your db to be up and running in `localhost` with the standard port.

Comment: I try to control my port and host, in MongoDB tutorial tell me, I should use default port. Consequently I didn't change defaulot configuration. The collection is exist, I can manipulate it with Command Prompt... Bud don't see it in pyhton code.

Comment: What does this print? `print client.database_names(); print client['db'].collection_names()`

Comment: You are connected to MongoDB. If there were a network error, or if MongoClient were misconfigured or the server were down, you'd see a ConnectionFailure exception at the line you call MongoClient(). Your collection is empty. I don't think you put the data where you think you did.

Comment: Sorry at  first, I was out of the office yesterday and couldn't see your answers. Thanks a lot for you collaboration. Messa, I print your statement with collection_names() and the output was total different from the collections I have in MongoDB. This output proves the hypothesis that the main problem is in connection between Python and MongoDB. Like A. Jesse Jiryu Davis tell, it is very probably that my collections are stored in other path. So, I should probably to change the argument by MongoClient() call... Nothing else, what I can improve at the moment